# Building JSON Response Object With GSON

Tags: android, gson

I've been parsing my Response to my Objects using `Gson`. Let's say for example I have a response like

```
"response": {
    "message": "Retrieved Successfully",
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "name": "Ken", "address": "NewYork", "phoneNumber":"00808493433"
         }
    }
}
```

I create my class like this

```
public class Gottenresponse {
private Response response;

public Response getResponse() {
    return response;
}

public void setResponse(Response response) {
    this.response = response;
}

public class Response {
    private String message;
    private Data data;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public class Data {

    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}

public class User {
    String name = "", address = "", phoneNumber = "";

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
}
```

But, what if my response is like this

```
"response": {
    "message": "Retrieved Successfully",
    "data": "{name: 'Ken', address: 'NewYork', phoneNumber:'00808493433'}"
}
```

Where the `Data` is in string format and I want to split the response and attach it to a Java POJO Object.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have any say in the format the server serializes in, you should ask them to use the first format you mentioned.  If you are stuck with a JSON encapsulated in a string, you can use a custom `TypeAdapter` to unwrap it. One way is to use a [`TypeAdapterFactory`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) so you can grab a delegate TypeAdapter when creating it.  The basic idea is to parse the `User` class by reading the string and then passing it back to gson to parse as as string instead of a field.

```
public class UserTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
  @Override
  public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
    if (typeToken.getType() != User.class) {
      return null;
    }
    return UserAdapter(gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, typeToken));
  }

  private <T> TypeAdapter<T> UserAdapter (final TypeAdapter<T> delegateAdapter) {
    return new TypeAdapter<T>() {

      @Override
      public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
        // Hand off the delagate, hoepfully you don't need to serialize in this ugly format
        delegateAdapter.write(out, value);
      }

      @Override
      public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        // Make sure the element is a string
        if(!in.peek().equals(JsonToken.STRING)) {
          // Not what we were expecting, could throw a parse exception here, too
          return null;
        }
        // Read the string and pass to the delegate adapter
        final String userData = in.nextString();
        // Need to create a new Reader because the data in the string is not strict JSON, so
        // must create a lenient reader for the string
        JsonReader userIn = new JsonReader(new StringReader(userData));
        userIn.setLenient(true);
        return delegateAdapter.read(userIn);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

You can then update you `Response` class to use the new factory, and optionally rename --

```
public class Response {
    private String message;
    @JsonAdapter(UserTypeAdapterFactory.class)
    @SerializedName("data")
    private User user;
    //...
}
```

You could also use a [`JsonDeserializer`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html), but `TypeAdapter`'s are preferred.

Comment: Yah. Exactly. That was what I did. And I noticed if I format the string very well before sending it to the server, it'll be easier for me to convert to JSON using Gson

Answer (score -1):

If it's your server, then you should modify server response

otherwise workaround can be making another Java Class called `Data`(`Data` should be same as `User` just with a different name)
then you can make the new `Data` pojo, and then convert it to `User`

Comment: Hey, it's not my server brov

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake in the response. Look at it again

Answer (score -1):

You could create a generic class Response. 
Sample code:

```
public class Response<T> {

    @SerializableName("message")
    private String message;

    @SerializableName("data")
    private T data; 

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;    
    }
}
```

Since you are using gson you can add a deserializer for the Response object. In that deserializer you have to convert that string for “data” key in a valid json string and parse it to that T parameter type.

Comment: Hey, getting the data is not the problem. Splitting the "Data" in the `data` object is the problem

Comment: In the deserializer you'll be able to check if the key "user" exists or not and parse the response from "data" according to this condition.